# Trouble migrating reusable django app models to use a custom user model

Tags: django, django-south, database-migration, django-1.5

I need to update an *existing* project to Django 1.5 to take advantage of its newly available custom user model. However, I'm having trouble migrating reusable apps that contain a model with a foreign key to a user. Currently, the foreign key points to `auth.User` but with a custom user model, it needs to point to `myapp.CustomUser`. Hence, some kind of migration is needed. I can't simply create a migration file for it because its a reusable app. It wouldn't be future proof because each time the app is updated, I would need to remember to create that migration again (there might even be migration conflicts) so it's not exactly a plausible solution.

Is there a solution to this problem other than to, maybe, fork each project, add a migration file, and then use that instead?

Some code:

`models.py` in reusable app

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

UserModel = getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', 'auth.User')

class ModelA(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel)
```

`models.py` in my project

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ...
```

`settings.py` in my project

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if the reusable app has a migration that creates a foreign key to a user, the following can be done to support Django 1.5's custom user model.

```
try:
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
except ImportError: # django < 1.5
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
else:
    User = get_user_model()

class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        db.create_table('reusableapp.modela', (
            ('user', self.gf('django...ForeignKey')(to=orm["%s.%s" % (User._meta.app_label, User._meta.object_name)])

    models = {
        ...
        # this should replace "auth.user"
        "%s.%s" % (User._meta.app_label, User._meta.module_name): {
        'Meta': {'object_name': User.__name__},
        }
        "reusableapp.modela": {
             'user': ('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey', [], {'to': "orm['%s.%s']"% (User._meta.app_label, User._meta.object_name)})
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it's being used in apps such as django-reversion.

However, this solution still can pose a problem if you originally started with `auth.User` and then changed to `myapp.customuser`, simply because south is honors AUTH_USER_MODEL but the migration for the custom user model hasn't been created yet. This can occur during testing. Ticket #1179 of south addresses this issue (http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/1179).

Comment: I have created a scrip that refactors South migration directories. Here: https://gist.github.com/benjaoming/5605160

Comment: In place of this, could one not do something like 
User = getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', 'auth.User') ... to=orm[User] ... 'to':"orm['%s']" % User ?

Comment: This solution indeed suffers from the runtime evaluation and resolution of User. So if you used auth.User in your site at version X then at version Y change it for a custom model, some or all of your migration scripts instantly become broken.

Comment: I guess the solution is for this to be taken into account in South, so that the appropriate frozen User model information is added to the migration info, rather than relying on a "smart" import based on the current settings.

In the meantime, this will work for any site that has no need to change from auth.User to a custom User (or from a custom User to another custom User, or even back to auth.User).